# How can I group/filter e.g. on movie genre or another detail on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

So I have some tracking in ga, but right now I am missing some options to group by. Lets say I have movies that each have a title, a genre and the year the movie is from. Right now I have tracking on events, but these events only have e.g.

(Category: Movies, Action: Play, Label: The Matrix) or

(Category: Movies, Action: Play, Label: Forrest Gump)

I want to group/filter these events by e.g. genre or year. I have this information, but not tracked in GA in these events. What is the convention to get more information linked up to these events in ga? Should this information just be added to the label?

Answer (score 0):

For events in Universal Analytics (not GA4) you can use custom dimensions to pass in additional information. This will require help from developer (to change the code) or if you know GTM you might be able to do it yourself.